# How can I set a flag to be flagged unlimited number of times?

Tags: flags

I have a flag on a node that anyone can flag. The flag is tied to a Rule that executes an action. Essentially I need to be able to allow any user to flag a node as many times as they wish and track the flag count.

The problem: It appears that with the [Flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag) module, the flag needs to be unflagged for the user to be able to flag it again. This essentially makes the flag count pointless as they are adding, removing and re-adding the same flag over and over.

Comment: The Flag module is essentially a bookmarking tool, and might not be suitable for what you are trying to do. If you could explain in a little more detail what you are trying to accomplish, perhaps a better solution might suggest itself.

Answer (score 0):

As Triskelion mentioned, the Flag module might be the wrong tool for your use case. Despite that, if you're looking to allow multiple flagging (instead a flag/unflag toggle) you can add a *Unflag a Node* action (or whatever your flagged entity is) to the other action you have on a flag event.

[image]